# storing NSUUID in Core Data causing error

Tags: swift, core-data, nsuuid

i'm currently trying to save bluetooth device's NSUUID into core data with my code as follow:

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
let newDevice = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Devices", inManagedObjectContext: context)
newDevice.setValue(connectingPeripheral.identifier, forKey: "identifier")
newDevice.setValue(TextField.text, forKey: "name")
do{
try context.save()
} catch _ as NSError{

}
```

error happens at

```
newDevice.setValue(connectingPeripheral.identifier, forKey: "identifier")
```

due to i can't store NSUUID into SQLite database. The only way i can think of is to convert the NSUUID into String and store into SQLite. But it is not so appropriate. Can anyone suggest me how to store NSUUID into SQLite? Thank you

Comment: Why is it inappropriate to convert it to a string?  NSUUID has a property, UUIDString, for that purpose.

Comment: Yup, i can convert it to string, but i would need the NSUUID to retrieve connection next time and so i would to convert the string back to NSUUID after i get from core data?

Comment: @pbasdf Okay, i have tried with convert to string, store to Core data, then retrieve it from Core Data in string type then i use following code 'DeviceList.identifier[indexPath.row] = NSUUID(UUIDString: test)!' to convert to NSUUID but it fails, i can't figure out why

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: hmm it could not unwrap string to NSUUID, but anyway i get it working with storing to attribute type "transformable"! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I wanted to save an `NSUUID` and later get back an instance of the same object, I'd declare the property to use the Core Data "transformable" type. For any class that conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol (which `NSUUID` does), Core Data will automatically invoke `NSCoding` methods to save/load an instance of the original class. Then I could just assign an `NSUUID` as the attribute value, and later read back an `NSUUID`, and Core Data would handle converting it to/from a form that it knows how to handle.

Comment: Yah it's working now, i just try to store with attribute type "transformable" and i got it works! Thank you very much!